# Validation for Excel sheet using core java

Tags: java, excel, apache

I have built core java code to read excel data and push into database. And it works fine. Now I want to add some validatation checks to the excel sheet. I am not able to do that. Consider I have some columns which are SettleDate,TradeDate, TradeID, IFStatus, IFVersion, IFDate, IFTime. I want to do below vlidation rules.

1. Settle should not be more thatn TradeDate.
2. TradID should be 14 letteres.
3. IFStatus, IFVersion, IFDate, IFTime should be blank

Below is my code........

```
try {
    Class forName = Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver");
    Connection con = null;
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sybase:Tds:tkbgssvt1:4105", "kauai_rwu", "rwu_kauai");
    System.out.println("Database connected to Sybase..");
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(
            "C:\\Users\\suresnar\\Desktop\\Mizu_FGloss\\Kauai_IN_Table_test.xlsx");                
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row;
    for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        row = (Row) sheet.getRow(i);
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        String TradeAction = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0));
        String TradeID = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(1));
        String Version = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(2));
        String TradeType = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(3));
        String Book = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(4));
        String Direction = row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue();
        String SafekeepFlag = row.getCell(6).getStringCellValue();
        String OurSettlePlace = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(7));
        String OurSettleDepot = row.getCell(8).getStringCellValue();
        String TheirSettlePlace = row.getCell(9).getStringCellValue();
        String TheirSettleDepot = row.getCell(10).getStringCellValue();
        String BrokerCode = row.getCell(11).getStringCellValue();
        String CustomerCode = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(12));
        String ProductCode = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(13));
        String TradeDate = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(14));
        String TradeTime = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(15));
        String CreditPerson = row.getCell(16).getStringCellValue();
        String Quantity = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(17));
        String Factor = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(18));
        String ActualQuantity = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(19));
        String SettleDate = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(20));
        String Price = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(21));
        String TradeCcy = row.getCell(22).getStringCellValue();
        String TradeValue = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(23));
        String AccDays = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(24));
        String TradeAICcy = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(25));
        String TradeAI = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(26));
        String SettleAmt = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(27));
        String RateCalc = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(28));
        String FxRate = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(29));
        String SettleCcy = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(30));
        String SettleAmtInFX = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(31));
        String Memo1 = row.getCell(32).getStringCellValue();
        String Memo2 = row.getCell(33).getStringCellValue();
        String Memo3 = row.getCell(34).getStringCellValue();
        String Memo4 = row.getCell(35).getStringCellValue();
        String Memo5 = row.getCell(36).getStringCellValue();
        String Remark1 = row.getCell(37).getStringCellValue();
        String Remark2 = row.getCell(38).getStringCellValue();
        String SelfStBrCode = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(39));
        String SelfStBrSubCode = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(40));
        String CustStBrCode = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(41));
        String CustStClCode = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(42));
        String CustStSubCode = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(43));
        String DiscretionFlg = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(44));
        String InputTime = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(45));
        String UpdateTime = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(46));
        String IFStatus = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(47));
        String IFVersion = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(48));
        String IFDate = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(49));
        String IFTime = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(50));
        String AzIFStatus = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(51));
        String AzIFVersion = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(52));
        String AzIFTime = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(53));
        String AzCKTime = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(54));
        String sql = "INSERT INTO FB_KAUAI_IN (\"my query\")";
        pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstm.execute();
        System.out.println("Imported rows " + i);
    }
    con.commit();
    pstm.close();
    con.close();
    input.close();
    System.out.println("Success import excel to mysql table");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle errors for Class.forName
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can anyone help me please?
your help is much appriciated...
Thanks,
Suresh N

Comment: what should happen if the checks fail? why dont you check it in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's a couple of different ways to do this:

- if you really own the Excel file and you create it. You can create your own formula to "validate" the cells you want.
- you can create different classes for each type you want to validate and each "cell" will have it's own class/validation
- you can manually create validation and apply for each field you want to validate (directly in java, per "String" you get from the
  excel file).
- since you (really) should change the SQL query to Hibernate for example, after that you can use hibernate validators (before inserting into db).

Comment: second solution is not really good. The best is the 3rd in my opinion